# Arduino State Machine

Tags: objective-c, arduino, rgb, led

This is a cross-post from someone who answered my original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986447/executing-multiple-functions-commands-on-arduino).

I'm not sure how to go about executing the 3 functions I'm after (as well as introducing even more than 3 in the future).

I am simply trying to Fade/Blink the selected Colour of an RGB LED (and perhaps introduce more functions in the future) where its RGB data is coming back from iOS and sent to an [RFDuino BLE module](http://www.rfduino.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/RFD22301.Data_.Sheet_.11.24.13_11.38PM.pdf).

Sends a "fade" string to the module picked up by `RFduinoBLE_onReceive (char *data, int len)` on the Arduino end.

```
- (IBAction)fadeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [rfduino send:[@"fade" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

- (IBAction)blinkButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [rfduino send:[@"blink" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

Selected Color:

```
- (void)setColor
{
    NSLog(@"colors: RGB %f %f %f", red, green, blue);

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];

    [colorSwatch setHighlighted:YES];
    [colorSwatch setTintColor:color];

    uint8_t tx[3] = { red * 255, green * 255, blue * 255 };
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)&tx length:3];

    [rfduino send:data];
}
```

This is originally how I set the RGB colour:

```
void RFduinoBLE_onReceive (char *data, int len) {
    if (len >= 3) {
        // Get the RGB values.
        uint8_t red = data[0];
        uint8_t green = data[1];
        uint8_t blue = data[2];

        // Set PWM for each LED.
        analogWrite(rgb2_pin, red);
        analogWrite(rgb3_pin, green);
        analogWrite(rgb4_pin, blue);
    }
}
```

This was the provided answer that now compiles on Arduino, but I have no idea how to actually execute my functions and where?

```
#include <RFduinoBLE.h>

int state;
char command;
String hexstring;

// RGB pins.
int redPin = 2;
int grnPin = 3;
int bluPin = 4;

void setup () {
  state = 1;

  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(grnPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluPin, OUTPUT);

  // This is the data we want to appear in the advertisement
  // (the deviceName length plus the advertisement length must be <= 18 bytes.
  RFduinoBLE.deviceName = "iOS";
  RFduinoBLE.advertisementInterval = MILLISECONDS(300);
  RFduinoBLE.txPowerLevel = -20;
  RFduinoBLE.advertisementData = "rgb";

  // Start the BLE stack.
  RFduinoBLE.begin();
}

void loop () {
  //RFduino_ULPDelay(INFINITE);
}

void processCommand (int command, String hex) {
  // hex ?
  // command ?
}

void RFduinoBLE_onReceive (char *data, int len) {
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    stateMachine(data[i]);
  }
}

void stateMachine (char data) {
  switch (state) {
    case 1:
      if (data == 1) {
        state = 2;
      }
    break;
    case 2:
      if (data == 'b' || data == 'f' || data == 'c') {
        command = data;
        hexstring = "";
        state = 3;
      } else if (data != 1) { // Stay in state 2 if we received another 0x01.
        state = 1;
      }
    break;
    case 3:
      if ((data >= 'a' && data <= 'z') || (data >= '0' && data <= '9')) {
        hexstring = hexstring + data;
        if (hexstring.length() == 6) {
          state = 4;
        }
      } else if (data == 1) {
        state = 2;
      } else {
        state = 1;
      }
    break;
    case 4:
      if (data == 3) {
        processCommand(command, hexstring);
        state = 1;
      } else if (data == 1) {
        state = 2;
      } else {
        state = 1;
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

**EDIT: Final code**

```
#include <RFduinoBLE.h>

// State properties.
int state = 1;
char command;
String hexstring;

// RGB pins.
int redPin = 2;
int grnPin = 3;
int bluPin = 4;

// Setup function to set RGB pins to OUTPUT pins.
void setup () {
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(grnPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluPin, OUTPUT);

  // This is the data we want to appear in the advertisement
  // (the deviceName length plus the advertisement length must be <= 18 bytes.
  RFduinoBLE.deviceName = "iOS";
  RFduinoBLE.advertisementInterval = MILLISECONDS(300);
  RFduinoBLE.txPowerLevel = -20;
  RFduinoBLE.advertisementData = "rgb";

  // Start the BLE stack.
  RFduinoBLE.begin();
}

void loop () {
  switch (command) {
    case 1:
      // Blink.
    break;
    case 2:
      // Fade.
    break;
  }

  //RFduino_ULPDelay(INFINITE);
}

// Converts HEX as a String to actual HEX values.
// This is needed to properly convert the ASCII value to the hex
// value of each character.
byte getVal (char c) {
  if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return (byte)(c - '0');
  else return (byte)(c - 'a' + 10);
}

// Process each function/command.
void processCommand (int command, String hex) {
  switch (command) {
    case 'b':
      command = 1; // Set blink mode.
    break;
    case 'f':
      command = 2; // Set fade mode.
    break;
    case 'c':
      // We put together 2 characters as is
      // done with HEX notation and set the color.
      byte red = getVal(hex.charAt(1)) + (getVal(hex.charAt(0)) << 4);
      byte green = getVal(hex.charAt(3)) + (getVal(hex.charAt(2)) << 4);
      byte blue = getVal(hex.charAt(5)) + (getVal(hex.charAt(4)) << 4);

      // Set the color.
      setColor (red, green, blue);
    break;
  }
}

// Sets the color of each RGB pin.
void setColor (byte red, byte green, byte blue) {
  analogWrite(redPin, red);
  analogWrite(grnPin, green);
  analogWrite(bluPin, blue);
}

// This function returns data from the radio.
void RFduinoBLE_onReceive (char *data, int len) {
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    stateMachine(data[i]);
  }
}

// Main state machine function, which processes
// data depending on the bytes received.
void stateMachine (char data) {
  switch (state) {
    case 1:
      if (data == 1) {
        state = 2;
      }
    break;
    case 2:
      if (data == 'b' || data == 'f' || data == 'c') {
        command = data;
        hexstring = "";
        state = 3;
      } else if (data != 1) { // Stay in state 2 if we received another 0x01.
        state = 1;
      }
    break;
    case 3:
      if ((data >= 'a' && data <= 'z') || (data >= '0' && data <= '9')) {
        hexstring = hexstring + data;
        if (hexstring.length() == 6) {
          state = 4;
        }
      } else if (data == 1) {
        state = 2;
      } else {
        state = 1;
      }
    break;
    case 4:
      if (data == 3) {
        processCommand(command, hexstring);
        state = 1;
      } else if (data == 1) {
        state = 2;
      } else {
        state = 1;
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some code [here](http://www.theskyway.net/en/converting-hex-as-a-string-to-actual-hex-values/) that you can use to convert hex characters to a byte.

So, you can add this to your existing code -

```
byte getVal(char c) 
{
       if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
         return (byte)(c - '0');
       else
         return (byte)(c-'a'+10)
}

void processCommand (int command, String hex)
{
      switch (command) {
           case 'b':
              command = 1;   // set blink mode
               break;
           case 'f':
              command=2;    // set fade mode
              break;
           case 'c':
              byte red=getVal(hex.charAt(1)) + (getVal(hex.charAt(0)) << 4);
              byte green=getVal(hex.charAt(3)) + (getVal(hex.charAt(2)) << 4);
              byte blue=getVal(hex.charAt(5)) + (getVal(hex.charAt(4)) << 4);
              setColor(red,green,blue);
     }
}

void setColor(byte red,byte green,byte blue)
{

// Set PWM for each LED.
        analogWrite(rgb2_pin, red);
        analogWrite(rgb3_pin, green);
        analogWrite(rgb4_pin, blue);
}
```

On the iOS side you can use something like this -

```
-(void) sendCommand:(char)command arg1:(Byte)arg1 arg2:(Byte)arg2 arg3:(Byte) arg3 {

    NSString *commandString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\001%c%02x%02x%02x\003",command,arg1,arg2,arg3];

    NSData *commandData=[commandString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    [rfduino send:data];
}

- (IBAction)fadeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self sendCommand:'f' arg1:0 arg2:0 arg3:0];
}

- (IBAction)blinkButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self sendCommand:'b' arg1:0 arg2:0 arg3:0];
}

- (void)setColor
{
    NSLog(@"colors: RGB %f %f %f", red, green, blue);

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];

    [colorSwatch setHighlighted:YES];
    [colorSwatch setTintColor:color];

    [self sendCommand:c arg1:red*255 arg2:green*255 arg3:blue*255];
}
```

Comment: What's `\001%c%02x%02x%02x\003`?

Comment: It is a string format that returns a string that starts with character 0x01 followed by the command character followed by the three bytes expressed as two digit hex numbers with a leading 0 if required followed by character 0x03